# How can i implement "OnChanges", on changes on the Backend

Tags: angular, frontend, observable, backend

I have a web page, and in that web page i am selling items.
I have one item of each type (one basketball, one pair of shoes, one football..).
I want to update all users if something sold.
For example, some user bought the last pair of shoes, so he will push the button "Buy now!". This will send HTTP request to the back to update the DB that the last pair of shoes just sold out, and ill want to send every user on my website an update HTTP request to refresh their web page with the new information that the pair of shoes just got sold(send a new list of items with "shoes": 0 for example).

sorry for all that intro, but my question is: how can i build a web page with initial data (of all my items), but that web page constantly listening to changes of that products?

Thanks!

Comment: you can use firebase for backend

Comment: I personally haven't used them, but whenever someone asks about getting live updates from a server they mention [web sockets](https://medium.com/dailyjs/real-time-apps-with-typescript-integrating-web-sockets-node-angular-e2b57cbd1ec1)

Comment: My back is already written in Django.

Comment: and isn't there a way using observables to do that thing?